# Pandas: How to display minor grid lines on x-axis in pd.DataFrame.plot()

Tags: python, pandas, plot

Is there a way to control grid format when doing pandas.DataFrame.plot()?

Specifically i would like to show the minor gridlines for plotting a DataFrame with a x-axis which has a DateTimeIndex.

Is this possible through the DataFrame.plot()?

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(csv_file, parse_dates=True, sep=' ')
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

this will plot S&p500 with minor xticks and grids at weekly frequency:

```
import pandas.io.data as web
ts = web.DataReader("^GSPC", "yahoo", start=dt.date( 2013, 6, 1 ))[ 'Adj Close' ]

ax = ts.plot()
xtick = pd.date_range( start=ts.index.min( ), end=ts.index.max( ), freq='W' )
ax.set_xticks( xtick, minor=True )
ax.grid('on', which='minor', axis='x' )
ax.grid('off', which='major', axis='x' )
```

[image]

Comment: nice one, but how can i do this using a DataFrame, as given in my question? I can't find an equivalent of ts.index.min(), for a DataFrame - df.idxmin() returns a series...

Comment: @user2846226 for a DataFrame `df.index.min()` should work as well, unless it is multi-index

Answer (score 56):

Maybe this feature didn't exist last year, but in version 0.19.2 you can do:

```
df.plot(grid=True)
```

See the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).

Answer (score 7):

`DataFrame.plot()` should return an `Axes` object from matplotlib.

So with `ax = df.plot(...)`, you can do:

`ax.xaxis.grid(True, which='minor', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.25, ...)`

Comment: awesome, i didn't realise that plot() returned an axes object. So I guess that a png graph is displayed in an IPython notebook in scilab mode because the notebook detects the presence of an axes object?